# SCIP: rerun of the problem without changing the model

Tags: c++, scip

I think I miss something in usage of SCIP library.

I have a MILP problem and want to compare the performance of the solver without an initial guess and with it in the frame of one executable problem. That is, I create a problem, solve it, then use the obtained solution as an initial guess and run the problem again.

But. The second run of the solver do nothing. I've read that after the first run of the solver, the stage of the problem is changed to `SCIP_STAGE_SOLVED`.

Then I've tried to find some method of the SCIP environment that changes the stage back, but there is no one (as far, as I understand).

After that, I've tried to introduce a fake variable into the model, but it does not change the stage too. Moreover, the approach leads to an error.

May be I need to create a copy of the problem? The first instance I solve without initial guess, the second one is run with it. The results are compared.

If I'm wrong, please, guide me on the right way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong then you simply need to call `SCIPfreeTransform` once (which removes everything except the original problem from the current scip instance). Then you can add your solution and solve again.

Comment: It seems to be. But it also deletes the obtained solution object. Is there any possibility to save the obtained solution from the first run and do not lose it after calling SCIPfreeTransform? The size of the problem does not allow me to pass the initial guess manually.

Comment: Did you copy the solution? Also you should take care to have your solution in the original space (since you might not have the exact same transformed problem after resolving). Both can be achieved with first calling `SCIPcreateSolCopy` and then `SCIPretransformSol` on the copied solution

Comment: Nope. So, the correct sequencing is: 1) solve the original problem; 2) obtain the solution and create a copy by `SCIPcreateSolCopy` and `SCIPretransformSol`; 3) create partial (or complete) guess solution by `SCIPcreatePartialSol`; 4) reset the model by `SCIPfreeTransform`; 5) add it to the model `SCIPaddSolFree`, isn't it?

Comment: Another question is following. If after solving the original problem I add one more variable (after reseting the problem) then that is why `SCIPretransformSol` is needed?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean that is why `SCIPcreatePartialSol` is needed? You need `SCIPretransformSol` in any case

Comment: Dear Leon, I made a small example. See: https://pastebin.com/rJNuU3wT. At the beginning of the file in the comment I described problems to be solved, then a procedure which should solve them. At the first part of the procedure I solve the first problem. Then copy the solution to external variables.

Comment: Afterwards, I make transformation the problem to the original state, add a new variable, create a partial solution object for this new problem, fill ALL variables with some values (the variables of the original problem by the optimal values and the variable by some arbitrary value obeying its value interval), and put this solution into the model object. Finally, line 164, I solve the new problem with the given initial guess (which is not actually partial). However, I get a message from the solver (lines 157-158), which mentions some strange value for the new variable x3.

Comment: What is happening? Why the given value is not taken into account? .............. The same message appears If I do not set any value to the new variable x3. So, what is the sense of a partial solution if the default values of the variables not set explicitly are taken into account?

Comment: That does seem weird, I will have time to look into that on tuesday

Comment: Leon, may be we will discuss the questions via email, if it is convenient for you. Unfortunately, not very detailed documentation does not allow me to answer my questions.

Comment: Feel free to reach out through email. I was off over Christmas but will be back tommorow and will hopefully have an answer for you then

Comment: Ok so I looked it over and everything is fine. SCIP checks two solutions: the best one of the previous solve (that one is infeasible because x3 is set to 0), as well as the one where you set x3 to 10. So your code example works correctly

Comment: But there is no the variable x3 in the solution after the first run. And the partial solution contains the var x3 with the pre-defined value. Where does the value x3 = 0  come from? And then what is exactly the sense of the partial solution?

Comment: Partial solutions are attempted to be completed in the completesol heuristic (`heur_completesol.c`). I really don't know how I could explain it more clearly. SCIP just checks the original solution from the first run (with all new variables set to their bound). That is where the message comes from. Your own new solution is correctly checked and added.